# Mail.app configured to access gmail, is there a way to sync "sent items"?

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail

I've decided I'd like to use only my @gmail.com email account.  I configured Mail.app to access my Gmail account and I can see the 'inbox' just fine.

However, when I send an email with Mail.app it does not appear in the 'sent items' at gmail.google.com.  And sending from gmail, it does not appear in the 'sent' folder of Mail.app.

Is there anyway to get the 'sent' mail to sync up in both clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the `Sent` folder for Gmail in the Mail.app sidebar (might be under a `[Gmail]` heading in Mail depending on how you set it up) then go to the `Mailbox` menu in the menu bar and look down near the bottom for the `Use This Mailbox For` menu.

Choose `Sent` in there and that should make the Gmail-based Sent folder the default place for Mail.app to save outgoing mail. It will also appear to move that `[Gmail]/Sent` folder out of the Gmail section and up to the top-most `Mailboxes` section below `Inbox`, etc.

After you do this you may notice you now have a section in the Mail sidebar for `On My Mac` folders, and a `Sent` folder in there. This is the folder that previously was containing all messages sent via Gmail but stored locally. Feel free to copy all the messages out of there and into the new default `Sent` folder (which will copy them all up to the Gmail server).

PS - This process works for `Trash` as well, so you can map the Gmail Trash to be used by Mail.app. You can also do it for `Drafts` but I've seen some weird behaviour where Gmail/Mail.app doesn't delete drafts after sending a message and you get a ton of them stacking up in Drafts, which is why I usually leave Drafts as a local-only folder.

Comment: thanks very much for all the help.  i didn't actually do all the steps you outlined because i never actually noticed that "GMAIL" section at the bottom of the sidebar in mail.app that shows the IMAP mailbox connection.  When I looked there I can see all the 'sent items' from both mail.app and the gmail web app.  Thanks!